# Variant cell heights that expand and contract when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have `TableViewController` Class that loads three different customer `cell` types. Which cell type is loaded into the `tableView` depends on what a `variable` that is selected else where. Each cell type is a different height and sometimes the height of the same type can be different depending on how much info there is inside the cells `text` and `image` fields.

Each cell has an expanded and unselected height when you click on each cell they expand.

Here is my code:

```
 // MARK: - Table View Settings
// Cell Settings
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 592
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 420
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch cellType {
    case CellName.Verbs.rawValue:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellType, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VerbCell
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return cell
    case CellName.Applicants.rawValue:
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellName.Verbs.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VerbCell
            tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellType, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ApplicantCell
            tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            scrollToSecondtRow()
            return cell
        }
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellType, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch cellType {
    case CellName.Verbs.rawValue, CellName.Applicants.rawValue:
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return selectedCellHeight
        }
        return unselectedCellHeight
    default:
        return 120
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch cellType {
    case CellName.Verbs.rawValue, CellName.Applicants.rawValue:
        // Adjust Height Of Verb Cells
        if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            selectedCellIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
            tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

// MARK: - Functions
func scrollToSecondtRow() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
}
```

The issue I am having is making an expanded view of each cell automatically adjust to cell height based on the contents of the cell height wich can range from 400 to 900 points depending on what's inside. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you set the row height? yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. And your custom cell will need to be setup to adjust its size based on content with auto layout

Comment: Each cell height is unselected cell height however when you click on the cell it expands and changes to selected cell height. Now I know how to make the cell height change based on the layouts in storyboard with constraints no problem. The issue I am having is that when I do that it conflicts with changing cell heights when you click the cell. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `UITableView` delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Also, implement `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to give to the `UITableView` an estimated size of the cell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return 120;
}
```

Alternatively, if your `UITableView` use the same estimated size for all cells, you could use:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Make sure that constraints of items inside the cell are adjustable and - only if your app supports versions prior to iOS 7 - return a fixed size inside `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.
Heres an easy tutorial to help you understand them better.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Does this method still allow for the cells to change from a set height say 200 points to full expanded so you can see the whole cell when clicked? I can make a cell reach its full height with autolayout the issue is it conflicts with my method above for the cell height changing when clicked. I need all cells to be say 200 points and when clicked they expand to reveal everything in the cell. When I use auto layout for the full height when the cell is small it squishes the contents

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom cell called resizable cell, which is just a cell with a label. The label is set with auto layout all edges to zero.

What I did was the unselected cell will have a set number of lines (in this case 2) and when selected this changes to zero which allows the label to grow to fit the text content which in turn will grow the cell to fit the label. This may differ from what you are doing exactly but this should point you in the right direction.

Tested it out and it is working.

Your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let data: [String] = ["Some really long string, Some really long string, Some really long string, Some really long string, Some really long string, Some really long string, Some really long string,Some really long string",
                      "some short string",
                      "some medium string, some medium string, some medium string, some medium string, some medium string",
                      "extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string, extremely long string"]

let cellId = String(ResizeableCell.self)
// if you will have multiple selected cells at once then create an array of selected indices
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: cellId, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//datasource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as! ResizeableCell
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.resizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.resizeLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    } else {
        cell.resizeLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        cell.resizeLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
    }
    cell.resizeLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPath != indexPath {
        // grow
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    } else {
        // shrink
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
}
```